# Finding nearest multiple of 3 to n, where n is an integer

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How would you define a function $g(n)$ to return the nearest multiple of $3$ to $n$? For example, if $n$ was a multiple of $3$, then $g(n)=n$.

More examples:
$g(5)=6$, $g(10)=9$, $g(34)=33$

Could this involve the modulo function? I've tried:
$g(n)=n-(n\mod3)$ and $g(n)=n\mod3$ but both do not hold true.

Can this even be done?

Comment: g(n) = 3*round(n/3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $g(n)=3\left \lfloor \frac{n+1.5}{3} \right \rfloor$

Comment: That is the floor function, where  $\lfloor x\rfloor$  is the largest integer not greater than $x$: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions

Answer (score 2):

The function 
$$
f(x)=3 \left \lfloor\frac{x+1}{3} \right\rfloor
$$
works just fine.

Comment: Is that brackets or some special notation?

Comment: Floor function.

Comment: Those brackets are a special notation. It means the closest integer that is smaller than the number on the inside. For example, $\lfloor 1 \rfloor =1$, $\lfloor \frac{1}{3} \rfloor =0$, $\lfloor -1.5 \rfloor =-2$.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically, this suffices to define the function $g$: "Let $g(n)$ be the nearest multiple of $3$ to $n$."

I'm guessing that you want to implement $g$ on a computer, using primitives like division and modulo. If so, you might have to be careful of integer overflows. If $g$ is required to input and output a signed 8-bit integer, then what is $g(-128)$? A naive implementation might return $-129\equiv+127\pmod {2^8}$. Would it be better to return $-126$ instead? Or maybe throw an exception? It depends on what you're trying to do.